# Ultimate Thread Group using inpur key value from csv

Tags: jmeter

[image]

Hi all  is it possible to take all value in csv file as an input for all thread running ? I thried to search for it , but did not get any of it , My scenario is like for every thread excuted , lets it take all value from csv file so that every possible input can be checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very possible because as Thread Group is being initialized **before** the CSV Data Set Config so you cannot set the number of threads from the CSV file beforehand as the CSV file is being read by each thread on each iteration.

If you want to parameterize the Thread Group with the CSV file you need to:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) to your test plan
2. Use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) somewhere in setUp Thread Group to convert JMeter Variable from the CSV file into a JMeter Property

   [image]
3. Use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the main Thread Group to read the value from the property

   [image]